# C++: unions with methods?

Tags: c++, methods, unions

Is there anything wrong with a union having one or more methods? Or anything to watch out for? (I can see constructors/destructors being problematic for schizophrenic reasons)

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with them except what you mentioned about the destructors and the freeing memory.

Comment: This is exactly why you can't have union members of a class/struct type that has a non-trivial constructor, destructor or assignment operator.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

From the C++03 & C++0x (Draft N3092) standards:

> **9.5 Unions**
>   A union **can have member functions (including
>   constructors and destructors)**, but **not
>   virtual (10.3) functions**. A union
>   shall not have base classes. A union
>   shall not be used as a base class.

Initializing the union using the aggregate initializer syntax (`U u = { 42 };`) or setting a member afterwards (`U u; u.i = 42;`) is not "problematic". And neither is initializing it using a constructor (`U u( 42 );`).
The only "catch" is that you cannot use the aggregate initializer syntax for a union that has a user defined constructor.

Comment: is this new for C++0x, or has it been part of the C++ standard?

Comment: @Jim: That part is unchanged.

Comment: unions can have constructors? then when is/isn't construction a problem?

Answer (score -12):

How could you possibly implement such a thing? Here's a pointer to a union, hope you don't mind that you have no idea which variables are safe to use and which aren't.

Unions are a dead language feature really anyway- they've been totally superseded by library-based methods like boost::variant or boost::any. Kind of similar to the void* and functional macros - they're very rarely useful in C++ compared to other options.

Comment: Don't forget the embedded world. Sometimes things aren't 100% typesafe.

Comment: @Jason: How does being embedded change anything? Either you know what type it is, so use a regular variable, you know all the types are related, so use polymorphism, or you need to know what type it is before you can do anything.

Comment: Embedded doesn't change anything about the language per se, but it does place limits on dynamic memory allocation and polymorphism (& much of boost is out) that bias you towards other techniques. Most often is a union between two 16-bit #s and a 32-bit #, or a union between a 16- or 32-bit # and a struct with bitfields. In those cases both members of the union have equally valid contents; it's both types.

Comment: One of C++'s strengths is that it does not forget that it is actually running on real world hardware, and unions are one of the tools that can greatly simplify this work.