# Is it possible to specify return types from bitwise manipulation?

Tags: c++, c++11, casting, bit-manipulation

Much of the code in place at the company I work for frequently uses unsigned char types for small numbers to avoid unwanted padding in data structures. I rarely see a problem with this, however I ran into a small issue with implicit conversion while setting error flags with bitwise operators.  I found a workaround by simply being explicit, but I was wondering if there was a more elegant way. Btw we compile with c++11

Given the error code enum below:

```
enum ErrorType : unsigned char
{
    OK.     = 0x00,
    ERROR01 = 0x01,
    ERROR02 = 0x02
};
```

and assuming I have some classes with private members of type errorType
which will use public members to set or unset flags, for example:

```
struct S
{
public:
void setError1();
void unsetError1();

private:
ErrorType errorType;
};
```

If I try to set values implicitly live below:

```
void S::setError1()
{
    this->errorType |= ERROR01;
}
```

I get type conversion errors

however if I explicitly cast the bitwise conversion it works

```
this->errorType = ErrorType(this->errorType | ERROR01);
```

It would appear that the problem is that the output of bitwise conversions is always an integer and does not necessarily reflect the input type.  Is this true? and if so is there a way to specify a type for it so I don't have to explicitly cast every time?

Comment: `enum ErrorType : unsigned char` - you probably want `enum class` there..

Comment: Create your own `ErrorType& operator|=(ErrorType& a, ErrorType b);`

Comment: @JesperJuhl not necessarily, though

Comment: Note: In the standard there are no operations on `char` or `short`. All operators work on at least `int` as a minimum. Thus `char` are converted to `int` before the operation. The result of the operation is the same as the input parameters (after conversion). See: [Implicit type conversion rules in C++ operators](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5563000/14065) Note the last rule: `Both operands are promoted to int`

Comment: @PiotrSkotnicki Sadly, you can't add methods to an `enum`. See also: [Can a C++ enum class have methods?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21295935).

Comment: @duskwuff it's a global operator, not a member one

Comment: @SergeyA Hence my deliberate/careful choice of the word "probably".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When no overload operator for the enums exist, the bitwise operation resort on the builtin operator version, after promoting the enums to their underlaying type, you can cast it explicitly as:

```
this->errorType = static_cast<ErrorType>(errorType | ERROR01);
```

or overload the `|=` operator to allow:

```
ErrorType& operator|=(ErrorType& lhs, ErrorType rhs) {
    lhs = static_cast<ErrorType>(lhs | rhs);
    return lhs;
}

void S::setError1()
{
    this->errorType |= ERROR01;
}
```

Comment: Very nice. But I think we should point out the subtly here. Note that you did not just override the `operator|` as that would have led to infinite recursion unless you manually convert the parameters to int. Overiding these operators has to be done carefully as there are automatic conversions that come into play and it is not always obvious what will happen.

Comment: @PiotrSkotnicki thanks, I was about to make that change.

Answer (score 1):

> It would appear that the problem is that the output of bitwise conversions is always an integer and does not necessarily reflect the input type. Is this true?

Since the early days of C, math operations on types **smaller than `int`** will promote the types to `int`.

The reasoning -- when `int` was "the big integer type" -- was that the promotion to `int` would be cheap and would prevent some overflow situations.

> if so is there a way to specify a type for it so I don't have to explicitly cast every time?

Yes!  Define the operation, rather than accept the default-generated implementation.

```
ErrorType& operator |= ( ErrorType &left, ErrorType right )
{
    return left = ErrorType(left | right);
}
```

Comment: @SergeyA where's infinite recursion ?

Comment: @PiotrSkotnicki my bad

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the result of a bitwise operation is an integral type after promotion. When two integral operands are participating in the arithmetic operation, they are first **promoted** to at least an `int` type, where the operation is performed on `int`s with a result being an `int`. There is no implicit conversion from `int` to enum, so you have to cast back yourself.

Here is more information on integral promotion rules: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_conversion#Integral_promotion